# Pandas QCUT Null Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
#Deciles
df_scored_final['2022_DECILE'] = df_scored_final.groupby(['CITY'],dropna=False)['SCORES'].transform(
                     lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10 ,precision=6, labels=[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])).astype(int)
```

I have this df_scored_final and i get an error becauses some of the scores are null. Is there anyway to do this on a df even though there are many nulls. Id rather apply this to the dataframe without dealing with a second dataframe without the null rows.

Comment: Please add a piece of data so we can manipulate and find the best solution.

Comment: Which error? Please provide entire or at least part of your dataframe and the expected output. Mention me with @Drakax when you've updated your question or I won't receive notification ;)